# How to use string instead of int? in C#

Tags: c#

I wish I could use this code with strings instead of integers

```
public static List<int> EvenlyDistribute(List<int> list)
{
    List<int> original = list;

    Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    list.ForEach(x => dict[x] = dict.Keys.Contains(x) ? dict[x] + 1 : 1);

    list = list.Where(x => dict[x] == 1).ToList();

    foreach (int key in dict.Where(x => x.Value > 1).Select(x => x.Key))
    {
        int iterations = original.Where(x => x == key).Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            list.Insert((int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)((list.Count + iterations) / iterations)) * i, key);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Usage in main:

```
 List<int> test = new List<int>() {11,11,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,19,19,19};
 List<int> newList = EvenlyDistribute(test);
```

Output:

```
19,11,13,19,14,11,19,15,16,19,11,17,18
```

is it possible to use this method but using strings?

Comment: No, you can't use that code above *as it's currently written*.

Comment: What does "evenly distribute" mean? Since you don;t actually use the list value can you just make the code generic by changing `int` to `T`?

Comment: @DStanley I think even distribution means symmetrical, I think it's more likely he means uniform distribution. I don't think the result he's showing is either.  Its weighted more toward the end of the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `int` with a generic type and replace the `==` with `.Equals` so that it will work with any type (including strings):

```
public static List<T> EvenlyDistribute<T>(List<T> input)
{
    if (input == null || input.Count < 3) return input;

    var dict = input.Distinct().ToDictionary(
        key => key, value => input.Count(x => x.Equals(value)));

    input = input.Where(x => dict[x] == 1).ToList();

    foreach (var kvp in dict.Where(item => item.Value > 1))
    {
        decimal count = kvp.Value;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            input.Insert((int) (Math.Ceiling((input.Count + count) / count) * i), 
                kvp.Key);
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rufus L work well. Was what I needed

Answer (score -5):

Try following :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> test = new List<int>() { 11, 11, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19 };

            List<int> newList = EvenlyDistribute(test); 

        }
        static List<int> EvenlyDistribute(List<int> input)
        {
            List<int> results = new List<int>();

            var groups = input.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());

            int max = groups.First().Count();

            for (int i = max - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    if (group.Count() - 1 >= i)
                    {
                        results.Add(group.Skip(i - 1).First());
                    }
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This addresses evenly distributing strings...